# How to remove words from the predictive dictionary in HTC Sense

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, htc-sense, dictionary, text-prediction

I have a case of irritating typos such as `yoi` rather than `you` etc. being selected by the otherwise excellent prediction, I must have accidentally taught the phone it in the past.

I had previously been able to remove them from the dictionary [as described in this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20457/how-to-clear-the-keyboard-autocomplete-suggestions) back on android 2.3 however surprise surprise **this menu pathway doesn't exist on HTCs version of 4.0 cupcake**. I'm really hoping this isn't going to be another case of [HTC quietly hiding features from their menus](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/21645/14154).

In the language and keyboard settings page, where I believe it was previously, it's not under the options button of `spelling correction` or the regionalisation button of `TouchInput correction`.

Does anyone know where this has been moved to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I was writing that question I stumbled upon the answer in a really convoluted menu pathway.  I was unable to find it in my prior research on the internet so I'll post it up in case anyone is looking in future.

1. Open the *settings app*.
2. Go to *Language & Keyboard*.
3. Touch the *Settings Button* next to *Touch Input* under *Keyboard & input methods*
   [image: Touch Input Slider Image]
4. Touch *Personal Dictionary*
5. Touch *Edit personal dictionary*
6. Press the menu button then touch *delete* then select incorrect entries to remove.

Comment: Just for the record: I have an Oukitel phone with Android 5.1. The personal dictionary can be found at: Settings / Language & input / Personal dictionary / <language>